# pandas combine not working for some rows in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas for combining two columns. Out of 86869 rows of my data, the following code worked for every row but did not work for 5425 rows.

```
import pandas as pd
person_file = "person.csv"  
input_folder = '~/Input/' 
df =pd.read_csv(input_folder + person_file) 
df['uniqueid1']=df['geo'].astype(str) +""+ df['unique_id_in_geo'].astype(str) 
df.to_csv('~/combine.csv', index=False)
```

For the not working rows, I am getting output like the following:

```
geo,unique_id_in_geo,uniqueid1
120530401011,1000,1205304010111000
120530401011,1001,1205304010111000
120530401011,1002,1205304010111000
120530401011,1003,1205304010111000
120530401011,1004,1205304010111000
```

I expected output like following:

```
geo,unique_id_in_geo,uniqueid_expected
120530401011,1000,1205304010111000
120530401011,1001,1205304010111001
120530401011,1002,1205304010111002
120530401011,1003,1205304010111003
120530401011,1004,1205304010111004
```

Am I doing anything wrong? ( I am currently adding a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: remove the quotes: `df['uniqueid1']=df['geo'].astype(str) + df['unique_id_in_geo'].astype(str) `

Comment: Still getting the same result. with: df['uniqueid1']=df['geo'].astype(str) + df['unique_id_in_geo'].astype(str)

Comment: What about df["uniqueid"] = df.apply(lambda row: row['geo'].astype(str) + row['unique_id_in_geo'].astype(str), axis=1)

Comment: getting this error: "'long' object has no attribute 'astype'", u'occurred at index 0

Comment: Strange, it seems you cannot convert a long to string. Try converting the two columns before and then apply the apply function. df["geo"] = df["geo"].astype(str) and df["unique_id_in_geo"].astype(str)

Comment: please post output from `df.info()`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 86868 entries, 0 to 219018
Data columns (total 16 columns):
unique_person_id    86868 non-null int64
geo                 86868 non-null int64
unique_id_in_geo    86868 non-null int64
````
uniqueid1           86868 non-null object
recode_elderly      86868 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(1), int64(13), object(2)
memory usage: 10.9+ MB

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I tried to recreate the error but i getting correct output .

Comment: I think I have figured it out. I was seeing the output in excel. The long number was showing incorrectly in excel. While I was using the notepad to view the CSV file, then the output result was showing correctly.